# Python extraction of date data from a binary file

Tags: python, binary, hex, extract

I have a file that I open in binary format using

```
with open(filename, 'br') as f2
```

I then need to extract certain blocks of Hex.  There will be lots of these 'dates' in the code that will look like:

> F2 96 E6 20 36 1B E4 40

I need to extract every instance of this in order for me to complete my date editing on it.  Each 'date' will end with hex char 40 as above.

I have tried regex but these do not seem to work as I want.

For example

```
re.findall(b'............\\\x40', filename)
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Why doesn't  regex work? What output does it give you? Also please provide more details on binary file format.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are confusing bytes with hex representation. `0x40` is a [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of the integer `64` and it's ascii code of the symbol `@`.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    results = re.findall('.{7}@', f.read())
    print results
```

Please note, that following regexps are equivalent: `'.{7}@'`, `'.......@'`, `'.......\x40'`

```
>>> print 0x40, hex(64)
64 0x40
>>> print chr(0x40)
@
```